# jquery dialog is sending multiple requests to the server in chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery-dialog

I am using jquery 1.4.2 version and jquery 1.8 ui version. with this when i am opening jquery dialog box in case of IE8, it is working fine and sending only 1 request. but when i tried this with chrome and firefox or IE10, it is sending multiple request to the server. kindly help on this.

below is the code Details:-

document.getElementById("hyperLinksFrame").src = fileName;

```
$('#hyperLinksFrame').dialog({
                title :'Link',
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 200,
                modal: true,
                resizable: true,
                autoResize: true,
                dialogClass: "ent_blue_iframe",
                buttons:{"Close": function(){
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }},
                        close: function(ev, ui) {
                            document.getElementById("hyperLinksFrame").src = "";
                            document.CICoverPageForm.userAction.value = 'addLinksOnCoverPage';
                            ajaxSubmit();
                            $(this).dialog  ('destroy');
                        }
                }).width(500).height(200);


<div id="parentHyperLinkDiv" style="display: none;">
 <iframe src="" id="hyperLinksFrame"> </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, I recommend using a more recent jQuery version; 1.4 is very old. Secondly, please show the code you're having trouble with. There simply isn't enough detail in this question for anyone to give meaningful assistance.

Comment: I have added the code. as we are using iframe in our code, we are using div as i have mention.